# the value of two vectors question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I do not know about the process to solve such problem like this,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Two vectors are parallel if one is a scalar multiple of the other i.e.
$$v\parallel w\iff v=kw,k\in\mathbb{R}$$
So to solve your problem essentially you need to find $\lambda$ such that
$$\lambda\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}=k\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, k\in\mathbb{R}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda+2 \\ \lambda+3 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} k \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, k\in\mathbb{R}$$
In general this reduces to solving these two equations simultaneously
$$\begin{align*}\lambda-1\cdot k&=-2 \\
\lambda-0\cdot k&=-3
\end{align*}$$
However, because the number are nice in this example you can just read off the value from the last component to get $\lambda=-3$.